# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. Ошибка сборки

Tags: java, android

поиском пользовался,но толкового ничего нет, чистил и делал ребилд проекта,студию перезапускал.
Ошибка:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

gradle.project

    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

gradle.module
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.potehki.potehki"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'

}

Message:

    Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
    :clean UP-TO-DATE
    :app:clean
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:checkDebugManifest
    :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2320Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72320Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library
    :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library
    :app:prepareDebugDependencies
    :app:compileDebugAidl
    :app:compileDebugRenderscript
    :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
    :app:mergeDebugShaders
    :app:compileDebugShaders
    :app:generateDebugAssets
    :app:mergeDebugAssets
    :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResources
    :app:mergeDebugResources
    AAPT err(Facade for 1734839208): libpng error: Read Error
    AAPT err(Facade for 615293122): libpng error: Read Error
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    > Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
    Information:BUILD FAILED
    Information:Total time: 9 mins 31.068 secs
    Information:1 error
    Information:0 warnings
    Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 1):

Я заметил, что у тебя гугловые библиотеки разных версий. Постарайся привести их к одной.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас ругается `libpng`.
Скорее всего картинки в ваших ресурсах криво сохранены или не верного формата и не могут быть прочитаны при сборке.
Откройте картинку в каком нибудь редакторе (к примеру фотошоп) и сохраните в `png`.

Прогоните все ваши картинки через этот сайт https://tinypng.com/

Comment: я все картинки через плагин drawable importer загружаю и они все в png

Comment: компилятор врать не будет, если  libpng ругается READ ERROR значит какая то импортированная картинка или найна патч не может быть прочитан. Может он повредился?

Comment: раньше писалась просто какая картинка,я пофиксил,а теперь без назвазвания,попробую все ресурсы пересмотреть

Comment: выполните Build - Clean Project

Comment: я в шапке указал,что делал это